# SilverStripe loop through hidden pages

Tags: hidden, silverstripe

How do I iterate only through all hidden pages in SilverStripe?

**$Children** excludes hidden pages. **$AllChildren** includes all pages. Is there a way to include only hidden pages?

Answer (score 4):

We can write a function to return only the hidden children like this:

```php
public function HiddenChildren() {
    return $this->AllChildren()->filter('ShowInMenus', false);
}
```

Then in our template we can loop through the hidden children like this:

```
<% loop $HiddenChildren %>
    $Title
<% end_loop %>
```

Comment: It totally makes sense to filter in DB when you have really much children.

Answer (score 3):

Well, a simple if in the template might do the trick:

```
<% loop $AllChildren %>
    <% if not $ShowInMenus %>
        $Title
    <% end_if %>
<% end_loop %>
```

See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/templates/syntax/#negation